# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined массив

Tags: javascript

```
var data = [{players: [{name:"1"},{name:"2"}]}];
for(var key in data) {
  var element = data.players[key];
  console.log(element);
};
```

Что делаю не так? Выбивает ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

На строчке `var element = data.players[key];`

Comment: `data[key].players;` - не там поставлен индексер, у `data` нет свойства `players`, а у `data[0]` - есть.

Comment: Точно! Спасибо)